# A potential supervisor said 'happy to supervise me for PhD', but I'm not in the minimum requirement. Is it guaranteed to be accepted? (UK)

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, university, united-kingdom

After the interview, a potential supervisor said: "Really Happy to Supervise You" with possible funding. However, the problem is that I'm not in the minimum academic requirement (grade) in the university admission (UK University).

In this situation, can I be accepted from the university for the PhD? Is it Guaranteed?? (* I did not apply officially yet).

Comment: It seems unlikely.

Comment: How did you get an interview? Did you apply through the university or directly contact the supervisor? If the latter, does the supervisor know about you not satisfying the requirements?

Comment: @GoodDeeds: it is the latter one. No, they did not ask, so I did not say it yet. It was a pretty long interview (about 1hour), and said really happy to supervise me.

Comment: @Buffy is it impossible?

Comment: Try it and you will find out.  Customs vary between universities.

Comment: Did “possible funding” mean funding was on offer or you had to find it?

Comment: The supervisor may say "yes" based on your background and interests. But if the grades do not make the formal limit for acceptance at the institution, I can only imagine exceptional circumstances which involve the supervisor's intervention (e.g. he knows your history and that you superated some difficult time) for you to be accepted. The latter is highly unlikely; an academic exposes themselves to very high risk by taking a student as an exception to going regulations. So, to emphasise Buffy's suggestion: "Very unlikely."

Comment: How did it go? please update us!

Answer (score 5):

Unlike some other countries, in the UK the supervisors do not have a lot of say in questions related to admissions and funding. Admissions are subject to university rules and these rules are rarely flexible, even if your potential supervisor really strongly supports your application. A student who does not meet minimal requirements is unlikely to be admitted for a program.

Most of the PhD programs in the UK are not funded from your supervisors' budget or their grant, but instead are funded through the Centers for Doctoral Training (which are funded from block grants to the University). Supervisors actually bid for a privilege of supervising a funded PhD student. To progress their career, academics in the UK must successfully supervise a certain number of PhD students. This means that academics are usually very happy to supervise any student who is successful in bringing in the funding. So even if your potential supervisor tells you that they are really happy to supervise you, don't assume that  they can and will go an extra mile to bend the university rules for you.

Comment: Thanks for an informative answer about UK practice.